# Orbot Apps VPN Mode - data leakage?

Tags: onion-services, orbot, vpn

Given an app configured to use Orbot's Apps VPN Mode, I am trying to determine how the VPN works. Most of the app's traffic is sent directly to a Tor hidden service the user controls, but some pieces of data are retrieved over https.

1. Can I be sure that all Internet traffic from the app is going through Tor?
2. If the app is forwarding some traffic (Bitcoin transactions) to a Tor hidden service (a `.onion` URL under the user's control), am I correct that there is no MITM concern for that portion of the data?

FYI: I am trying to verify the information in this guide is correct with regards to Orbot:
https://github.com/jonathancross/jc-docs/blob/master/Bitcoin_mobile_privacy.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use your own software AP and `tcpdump` to verify it. In my case it worked fine, **but not on device boot-up**
2. In Tor it's impossible to make MitM unless you're doing it *directly* at the point of dot-onion service host.

the guide you've referenced seems to be sane and working as described